# How can I make Bluejeans logo display:none inside iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe, bluejeans

```
<iframe src="https://bluejeans.com/242424242400/2424/quick?embed=true&amp;parent=https://events.zenevent.org&amp;name=Administrators__Zenevent&amp;footer=false&amp;apps=false&amp;copy_link=false&amp;rating=false&amp;app_pitch=false" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; microphone; camera; display-capture" noresize="true" style="width: 100%; height: 650px; border-radius: 0px; border: none;"></iframe>
```

**This is the bluejeans iframe I'm using**

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to change the styling/ content of the Iframe unless you have direct access and therefore ownership of the source html and/or css files.

Otherwise you are violating the Cross Site Scripting policy.